# Variable Not Being Initialized in Function

Tags: java, string, variables, methods, initialization

I'm trying to create a program that prompts user to input a word and it would return the length of the words. However I'm having issues with "String word;", as I keep getting the error that local variable may not have been initialized.

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FunctionsTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String word;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The length of the word is" + findLength (word));

}//End of Main Method

public static int findLength(String word) {

    String str = new String(word);

    return str.length();

 }//End of findLength Method
}
```

Comment: Which word do you want to find the length of? You're never providing a word, how do you expect your program to work and what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

the "word" has no value,it's null,  you need give "word" some value:

```
String word = "abc";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no user input being prompted, therefore the String word will never have a value. Create a user input prompt, and have the string equal to the value of the input.